# How to print full REST URL in SoapUI's groovy

Tags: rest, api, groovy, automation, soapui

If I am using `getProperty("Endpoint")`, it is giving me only domain name.
I want to get whole url with parameters and filters.

Answer (score 0):

You should be to get it in the [Script Assertion](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/using-script-assertions.html) for the same request step using below statement.

```
log.info messageExchange.endpoint
```

[image]